# Define an event in C# windows form when a property has changed value

Tags: c#, properties

I had a very basic class with 1 property like this:

```
public class NodeItem
{
    private object _Value;

    public object Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value; }
    }
}
```

How can I define an event whenever `Value` property's value changed?

Comment: Define an event and in the setter for the property, set the value and also fire the event if the value has changed. You can use more than one line in the `set {}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private object _Value;
public object Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
        _value = value;
        // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
        OnPropertyChanged(value);
    }
}


protected void OnPropertyChanged(object val)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(val));
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)

for Subscribing to event

```
void MyEventSubscription(object sender, CustomEventArgs a)  
{  
    // Do something useful here.  
}  

myClassInstance.PropertyChanged += MyEventSubscription;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. And how does I use that even in my code pls.